# Updated list of EVM Opcodes

Tags: evm, opcode

Is there an updated Opcode Specifications available for the EVM to date?

Specifically, is there a continuously updated list of Opcode Specifications similar to that found in the ethereum yellow paper?

Comment: What's wrong with the Yellow Paper? It contains the number of stack words which are popped and pushed by each operation which you request below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solidity documentation has a mostly mostly-up-to-date listing of opcodes and the arguments they take.

https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.23/assembly.html#opcodes

Comment: I guess I have to assume that the number of parameters specified are coming of the stack.

Comment: Yes they are. I have a very basic example here, hopefully it helps https://github.com/postables/Solidity-Modules/blob/master/Contracts/Factory.sol

Answer (score 1):

**Yes.**

It's [here](https://github.com/trailofbits/evm-opcodes), on Trail of Bits' github.

Comment: Do you know a list that includes the number of arguments that each opcode needs of the stack?

Comment: Nope, I don't know any list like that.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a difinitive answer to locating an updated listed of Opcodes Specifications. Here is the updated Yellow Paper on Github https://github.com/ethereum/yellowpaper